# Adding header title in multiple charts

Tags: c#, charts

[image]

```
         {
        rand = new Random();
        ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();

        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        ds = GameLib.Reports.GetReportList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

            Chart2.Series.Add("Series" + i.ToString());
            Chart2.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea" + i.ToString());


            Chart2.Series[i].ChartArea = "ChartArea" + i.ToString();


            Chart2.Series[i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

        }

        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            Chart2.Series[("Series" + k).ToString()].Points.DataBindXY(ds.DefaultView, "ReportID", ds.DefaultView, "ReportName");
        }
    }
```

This is code to create multiple charts.

Can anybody help me to create multiple chart headers?

**i.e** 
 i have attached output image,actually each chart has a title,so i want to display the title of each chart.

Comment: i suggest you using zedGraph

Comment: btw what do you mean by chart header ?

Comment: Here i am creating a multiple chart area, each chart area should contain name; example ChartArea0 have Report0 like that;can you help me to solve this/

Comment: i really wish i help but still can't understand what do you want! can you do some simple explanation like image with paint or something similar, i advise you to make your questions VERY clear in order to get answers from ppl here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add individual titles to your chart, and then you should dock them to a chartarea.
Like so:

```
// Add the title
Chart1.Titles.Add("Title1");

// Set the text of the title
Chart1.Titles("Title1").Text = "Chart Area 1 Title";

// Dock the title to a ChartArea
Chart1.Titles("Title1").DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1";
```

You can use something like this in a loop or create them all individually.

**edit:**

```
Title tt = new Title(); 
tt.Name = "ChartArea1" + t.ToString(); 
// tt.Text = "Performance Warehouses"; 

Chart1.Titles.Add(tt); 
Chart1.Titles[tt.Name].Text = UserName; 
Chart1.Titles[tt.Name].DockedToChartArea = tt.Name; 
Chart1.Titles[tt.Name].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false
```

Comment: Thank you;for this some more modification: Title tt = new Title();
                        tt.Name = "ChartArea1" + t.ToString();
                        // tt.Text = "Performance Warehouses";
                        Chart1.Titles.Add(tt);
                        Chart1.Titles[tt.Name].Text = UserName;
                        Chart1.Titles[tt.Name].DockedToChartArea = tt.Name;
                        Chart1.Titles[tt.Name].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;

Comment: Did I answer your question or do you need some more help? Otherwise you could mark it as the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
  
•To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.